How can I restrict the set of operations allowed on a JavaScript value using TypeScript?
I have some JavaScript objects which supply many operations, some of which are not valid depending on the runtime (yet constant) state of the object. I wish to use TypeScript to restrict the set of operations available on these objects, so that invalid ones cannot be called.
I've been able to achieve that by defining a discriminated union and asserting it as the type of my objects.
This approach works, however it has an issue: I don't know how to use TypeScript to make sure that my objects and the discriminated union are compatible, since I'm forcing the type through an assertion.
To further complicate things, I'd like to use this approach to type certain kinds of objects without looking at their state, since they rely on laziness.
Minimal example
Here is a very minimal, silly example to show what I'm trying to do. You can interactively play with this (there are small unimportant differences) here: https://tsplay.dev/Wk18pN
I have a class MyNum which wraps a number. Some of its operations are available only for some kinds of numbers. For instance, round() can only be called on non-integers, while incr() can only be called on integers:
class MyNum {
  n: number;
  get isInt() { return this.n%1 === 0; }
  
  constructor(n: number) { this.n = n; }

  incr() {
    if(!this.isInt) throw new Error(`incr() can only be called on integers`);
    return this.n+1;
  }
  round() {
    if(this.isInt) throw new Error(`round() can only be called on integers`);
    return Math.round(this.n);
  }
}

Problem
I wish to use TypeScript to statically make sure that incompatible operations cannot be called. I want to get a static error if I try to do the following:
function f(n: MyNum) {
  // the following line should fail at compile time,
  // since it can fail at runtime, if `!n.isInt`
  n.incr();
}

My solution
I was able to achieve what I want using a discriminated union, where some operations are available only for some subtypes. Then I just have to cast MyNums to such union:
type NumBase = {
  n: number;
  isInt: boolean;
}
interface Int extends NumBase {
  isInt: true; // discriminant
  incr(): number;
}
interface Real extends NumBase {
  isInt: false; // discriminant
  round(): number;
}
type Num = Int | Real;

// with this I can create a `Num` (by casting a `MyNum`)
function myNum(n: number): Num {
  return new MyNum(n) as unknown as Num;
}

And this allows me to write the following type-safe code:
// this fails statically (as expected)
function f(n: Num) {
  n.incr(); // Error: Property 'incr' does not exist on type 'Num'
}

// this works (as expected)
function g(n: Num) {
  if(n.isInt) {
    n.incr() // OK, since `n` is `Int` in this branch
  } else {
    n.round() // OK, since `n` is `Real` in this branch
  }
}

Problem with my solution
The problem is that TypeScript doesn't make sure that Num and MyNum are compatible. If I have a typo in one of the fields of Num I would get no error. For instance if I had written...
interface Int extends NumBase {
  isInt: true; // discriminant
  inxr(): Int; // notice the typo: `inxr` vs `incr`
}

...TypeScript would still accept the program. It doesn't realize that MyNum has no inxr field.
Further complication: laziness
I'd like to use this approach for lazy objects too. That means that I'm not allowed to look at the objects' state in order to type them, since that would force strictness:
class LazyNum implements NumBase {
  protected readonly compute: () => number;
  protected _n: number | undefined;
  get n() {
    if( this._n === undefined ) this._n = this.compute();
    return this._n;
  }
  get isInt() { return this.n%1 === 0; }

  constructor(compute: () => number) {
    this.compute = compute;
  }

  incr() { return this.n+1; }
  round() { return Math.round(this.n); }
}
function lazyNum(compute: ()=>number): Num {
  return new LazyNum(compute) as unknown as Num;
}

Again, this still works fine, but it has the same problems above. It might just make it a bit harder to define lazyNum in a type safe way.
Question
How can I restrict the set of operations available on a JavaScript object using TypeScript in a type safe way?

You could muck around with using this parameters and a custom type guard method but you need isInt() to be a method, not a getter (without ms/TS#43368). See this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

I didn't realize you could use this in a type guard that way. That's cool.

@jcalz: yes, what you're suggesting would works, thanks! I hadn't considered the idea of using the this parameter to "enable" methods.

Thinking about it, these types in the program I'm working on aren't binary: if I could re-design the whole thing in TS, I'd have a union of ~6 different types and instead of the isInt boolean, I'd need an id: "A"|"B"|"C"... discriminant. Custom type guards would only let me discriminate one type out of the whole union (while discriminants would let me discriminate between all the types at once). Is there a similar clever trick to discriminate between the many types my union would be made of?

I'm in the middle of writing an answer and this followup question is out of scope for this question as asked. If you want that to be answered you should consider opening a new post for it.

OK, sure. I might do that after you answer.

You can't really do this easily, especially with isInt being a getter. If you allow isInt to be a method, you can get the behavior you're talking about, but it's pretty messy.  Like this:
class MyNum {

    n: number;
    isInt(): this is { __isInt: true } {
        return this.n % 1 === 0;
    }

    constructor(n: number) { this.n = n; }

    incr(this: { __isInt: true } & MyNum) {
        if (!this.isInt()) throw new Error(`incr() can only be called on integers`);
        return this.n + 1;
    }
    round(this: this extends { __isInt: true } ? never : MyNum) {
        if (this.isInt()) throw new Error(`round() can only be called on integers`);
        return Math.round(this.n);
    }
}

const n = new MyNum(123);
if (n.isInt()) {
    n.incr(); // okay
    n.round(); // error
} else {
    n.incr(); // error
    n.round(); // okay
}

The idea is that isInt() is a custom type guard method, that pretends that isInt() returning true adds a phantom __isInt property of type true to the instance.
This can't work when isInt() is a getter, since getters can't return type predicates.  There's an open feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#43368 to support that, but for now it's not possible.

Anyway, the incr and round methods use a this parameter to check whether there's an __isInt property of type true in the instance. If so, then incr() is allowed (because this is assignable to {__isInt: true}) and round() is disallowed (because this is not assignable to the conditional type this extends { __isInt: true } ? never : MyNum).  If not, then the reverse happens.
The type for round() is more complicated because if isInt() returns false then MyNum is not narrowed, and round() needs to check for the non-narrowed case. The conditional type basically performs the equivalent of an Exclude, so that if this has been narrowed, you get never (which fails), otherwise you get MyNum (which succeeds).

This works, but I don't know that I'd recommend such an approach. I'd only consider it if you couldn't refactor your code away from a single class with disallowed behaviors based on state... but if you can't refactor then isInt() probably can't be changed from a getter to a method.  But it's at least close to what you're asking for.
Playground link to code

Thanks, this solution is the best one I found so far, and your explanation is very clear. I will create a new question asking how to handle union of multiple types.

but if you can't refactor then isInt() probably can't be changed from a getter to a method

I cannot change isInt from getter to method, as it would break existing code. But I am allowed add new methods and new getters and tell the TypeScript users to use those. This means I should be able to implement your solution.

I see what you're trying to do here, and I have a few suggestions, but I'm not 100% sure that you are going to be able to totally achieve what you're after. We'll see.
First, I would say having a class where you have operations that may or may not be valid is something of an anti-pattern, what you want is a factory that returns the correct type based on it's argument:
class Int implements NumBase {
  isInt = true

  constructor(public n: number) { }

  incr(): number {
    return this.n + 1;
  }
}

class Real implements NumBase {
  isInt = false

  constructor(public n: number) { }

  round(): number {
    return Math.round(this.n);
  }
}

type Num = Int | Real

function numFactory(n: number): Num {
  if (Math.round(n) === n) {
    return new Int(n);
  } else {
    return new Real(n);
  }
}

Now you can't call the wrong method on the wrong type, the compiler won't let you without discriminating the union first, and you can call the factory with a statically known constant or a dynamic value from a network call and get back the correct type. And for your inxr example, you'd get a pretty quick compile error as soon as you tried to use it (for example in a unit test).
I also am not sure I fully understand the point of the LazyNum class, sticking with the theme here if you don't have a number yet to pass in rather than having the n property be potentially undefined and "mixing" the two incompatible types I would just defer instantiating the class and call the factory when things are ready.
I realize you want to hide the laziness behind a facade but there's no way to statically type it if you do that. You could have the protected _n be a Num and just throw at runtime if the caller accesses the "wrong" method, essentially forcing callers to check isInt. For correct method calls LazyNum can just delegate to it's protected Num instance, but you aren't going to be able to make that LazyNum class work in any sort of statically verifiable way, and the OO pattern to handle this is to just use a factory.
I guess the question is, how much of your design are you willing to rework to buy these improvements in type-safety? A question only you can answer, but I've outlined here an approach you could take if you decide it's worth it.
Edit
Considering the comment by jcalz: that lets you have your cake and eat it too to some degree and may be a better approach for what you want. Just make sure the logic in your custom type guard is correct, as that still is functionally an assertion to the compiler (which, to be clear, does not make it bad).

With your suggestion, how would you handle LazyNum? I was asking specifically about how to type existing JS object, not about re-implementing them in TS.

@BlueNebula the unsatisfying answer is... I'd probably give up on compile type safety and good intellisense and just insert runtime checks (bear in mind I don't know your actual use case). The solution by jcalz at least gets you the intellisense back, and user-defined type guards are a pretty solid way to do runtime checks.

But really I stand by what I said (and despite the solution by jcalz) in my answer: having a data type (even conceptually, this isn't just about static analysis) where some operations are invalid depending on internal state is an antipattern. If you're modeling for example a state machine and the different states are different things then model it that way in the code rather than bending the language in an attempt to be clever. In other words, if it were me I would change the JS implementation with or without Typescript. You have two different things, not one thing with two states.

I see what you mean, and I do mostly agree with you. The issue is that these JS types already exist and are shared between a few projects in my company. I'm trying to port some projects of my team to TS, but don't have the freedom to make API-breaking changes to this code. I could fight for it, but since there are mostly working solutions, it would be easier to use those and save my fighting power for stuff that really needs to be changed. I'm sure I'll be able to further improve this stuff in the future, but for now I'd like to add TS types to JS without breaking the latter.

@BlueNebula I totally get it, you pick and choose your battles. I think the solution by jcalz is about as good as you're going to get then.
